# reordering filenames in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, listdir

I have the following problem:

I need to load several data files. The files are named by my device like:

```
meas98.dat
meas99.dat
meas100.dat
meas101.dat
```

With other words, there are no leading zeros. Therefore, if I get the filenames via

```
os.listdir
```

they are ordered alphabetically, meaning "meas100.dat" will be the first one. This is obviously not what I want to achieve. The question is what is the most elegant way of doing this?

The (unelegant) way I came up with is:

- load the filenames
- extract the filenumber
- order the filenumber (get the indices)
- order the filenames with those indices

I am pretty sure python has something build in that can do this while loading the files...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: Write some custom lambda function to sort function. sort by filename.split('.')[-1].replace('meas')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will suit your problem:

```
import re

l = ['meas100.dat',
     'meas101.dat',
     'meas98.dat',
     'meas99.dat']


sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(re.match('\D*(\d+)', x).group(1)))
```

Output:

```
['meas98.dat', 'meas99.dat', 'meas100.dat', 'meas101.dat']
```

Comment: I have no idea why you got downvoted. I selected it as accepted, since it is in my opinion the most elegant solution

Answer (score 7):

```
l = ['meas98.dat',
    'meas99.dat',
    'meas100.dat',
    'meas101.dat']
l.sort(key=lambda i: int(i.strip('meas.dat')))
```

There is a pythonic way to do this by using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module:

this is the files in my ternimal:

```
~/so$ ls
meas100.dat  meas98.dat  meas99.dat
```

this is the files in python:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/home/li/so/')
list(p.iterdir())
[PosixPath('/home/li/so/meas99.dat'),
 PosixPath('/home/li/so/meas98.dat'),
 PosixPath('/home/li/so/meas100.dat')]
```

looks like the `pathlib` has do this sort for you, you can take a try.

Comment: @Glostas please accept an answer to close this question, this will save other people's time.

Comment: As of today [the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir): "The children are yielded in arbitrary order"

Answer (score 3):

Using `slicing` `[4:-4]` to get only numbers from filename - and `sorted()` will use them to sort filenames.

```
# random order
l = [
    'meas98.dat',
    'meas100.dat',
    'meas99.dat',
    'meas101.dat',
    'meas1.dat',
]

sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[4:-4]))

print(l)
```

result

```
['meas1.dat', 'meas98.dat', 'meas99.dat', 'meas100.dat', 'meas101.dat']
```